# How to create a validation on textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 textboxes, I want to create a validation in textbox. For Example textbox1 value is 10, then textbox2.1stquarter value is 5, textbox3.2ndquarter should have atleast 5 or  lower than 5. If the combine value of textbox2 and textbox3 is equal to 10 allow it but if the combine value of textbox2 and textbox3 is greater than 10 should not allow it. How to do it?

Just like this code. I want to get the value of textbox1so the two other textbox should have >10

```
function CompareValues() {
   var textBox1=document.GetElementById('ID_OF_TextBox1');
   var textBox2=document.GetElementById('ID_OF_TextBox2');
   var textBox3=document.GetElementById('ID_OF_TextBox3');

   if ( textBox1.value>textBox2.value + textBox3.value ) {
      the value is greater than textbox1
   }
}
```

Comment: Its always easy to make a man run if he is walking. Stackoverflow can help you, if you have tried a little and give us little code.

Comment: so you need to return the value of textbox1 if the sum of textbox2 and textbox3 is greater than 10..??

Comment: yes just like that, return false if greater than 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seriously you could have done it by yourself mate... Check if the below fiddle helps u... :)

```
var textBox1=document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
     var textBox2=document.getElementById('textbox2').value;
    var textBox3=document.getElementById('textbox3').value;

    if((+textBox2 + +textBox3)  >= 10){
                $('#textbox1').val('');
                $('#textbox2').val('');
                $('#textbox3').val('');
        return false;
    }else{
    alert('value ok');
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B5cKr/

Comment: it works fine here.Check if u have enabled the jquery library 1.7

Comment: it works, if is it possible that automatically return false if the value is greater than textbox1, I don't want to check it using submit button?

Comment: then on what condition are you validating the text fields mate..???hope u got my point...!!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" />
<input id="txt2" type="text" />
<input id="txt3" type="text" />
<DIV id="btnValid">CLICK</DIV>
```

**JS:**

```
    $("#btnValid").on('click', function () {
    var txt1 = $("#txt1").val();
    var txt2 = $("#txt2").val();
    var txt3 = $("#txt3").val();
    var combine_2_3 = Number(txt2) + Number(txt3);

    if (Number(txt1) > Number(txt2) || Number(txt1) > Number(txt3)) {

        if (Number(txt1) > Number(combine_2_3)) {
            alert("txt1 value is greater then combine value ");
        }
       else {
            alert("combine value txt2, txt3 is greater then txt1");
             $("#txt1").val("");
             $("#txt2").val("");
             $("#txt3").val("");
          }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8xFVB/)**

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8xFVB/4/)**

Comment: the combine value of textbox2 + textbox3 should not greater than textbox1. And how to automatically delete the entered data on textbox if false?